# Changing Azure web role name?

Tags: azure, azure-web-roles, azure-powershell

Is it possible to change a web role name through PowerShell or any other programmatic way without needing to change the project name itself? We need role name change for monitoring purpose and changing project name would require a lot of work for us with modifying build definitions.

Comment: Do you want to change the name of the role e.g. from `WebRole` to `NewWebRole` or the project itself?

Comment: No, just the role name.

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be a work around way which is from a [blog](https://michaelcollier.wordpress.com/2013/10/25/setting-a-webworker-role-name/) of a MS developer, to update role name via modify the Role schema file.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Added attribute vmName `<Role name="WebRole1" vmName="CollierWeb">` in the .cscfg.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Rename Azure Cloud Service.ps1

```
import-module Azure

# download publish settings
Get-AzurePublishSettingsFile

# import settings you just downloaded
Import-AzurePublishSettingsFile "C:\Users\<user>\Downloads\MySub-DATE-credentials.publishsettings"

# view subscription details



Get-AzureSubscription

# select active subscription
Select-AzureSubscription 'MySub'

# view cloud services for selected sub
Get-AzureService 

# update cloud service name/description
Set-AzureService 'myServiceName' 'Friendly Service Name' 'Detailed Service Description'
```

Comment: My question was on updating _role name_, not cloud service.